# Criar barra com CSS

Tags: css

Um cliente pediu para criar um menu baseado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia fazer essas barras com CSS? Estou usando o Bootstrap para o desenvolvimento.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
 <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto main-nav-left">
   <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Esportes</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Masculino</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Feminino</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Crianças</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Outlet</li>
   <li class="nav-item">Lançamentos</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiz essa opção usando só o caractere `/` mas vc pode criar o elemento que quiser no `::after` da `LI`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  padding: 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background-color: green;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
  position: relative;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "/";
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto main-nav-left">
    <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Esportes</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Masculino</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Feminino</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Crianças</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Outlet</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Lançamentos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, Hugo. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Fox.11 sem problemas meu caro